# I want to delete file from server by bash script using ftp

Tags: bash, curl, ftp, delete-file

I want to delete file by bash script using ftp

I use below code

```
 $file = xyz/ab/file.txt
 curl -v -u  $user:$pass ftp://server.com/$file -Q "DELE $file"
```

but it's give these error

> *Entry path is '/'
>   DELE xyz/ab/file.txt
>   * ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
>   < 550 Could not delete xyz/ab/file.txt: No such file or directory
>   * QUOT command failed with 550

How can I delete file with single line bash script command

Comment: Your code is not syntactically valid shell script, and could not possibly produce the error message you report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to delete file from ftp server with curl:

```
user="foo"
pass="bar"
dir="xyz/ab/"         # with trailing slash
file="file.txt"

curl -v -u "$user:$pass" "ftp://server.com/$dir" -Q "-DELE $file"
```

or

```
curl -v -u "$user:$pass" 'ftp://server.com' -Q "-DELE /$dir$file"
```

or without leading `/`

```
curl -v -u "$user:$pass" 'ftp://server.com' -Q "-DELE $dir$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ftp` command if you want to add additional commands.

```
user=foo
user=bar
ftp -n 127.0.0.1 <<EOF
quote USER $user
quote PASS $pass
delete xyz/ab/file.txt
exit
EOF
```

Deleting must be available on the ftp server, however. If I remember correctly, for vsftpd you must set `anon_other_write_enable=YES` in /etc/vsftpd.conf